# Ruby on Rails progress bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create file upload progress bar in my Rails application. I am Googling but couldn't find appropriate answer. Can anyone please suggest me how can implement the file upload progress bar on Rails .... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Have you given [SWFUpload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) a look?

Comment: approve this answer - you should use flash based solution, because it most reliable

Comment: Not if you want to send *any* other form data along with the file data. SWFUpload works, but knowing who uploaded it, and possible file context data is a must on many applications..

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial explains how to mix SWFUpload and Paperclip (if you haven't it already, you definately should have)

http://jimneath.org/2008/05/15/swfupload-paperclip-and-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 0):

We've used Uploadify (add .com for the website) (requires jQuery) with Paperclip and had pretty good luck. Nested model forms and multiple uploads are trickier (same problems will be present with SWFUpload), but for the simple case of a single upload, even 100MB uploads (make sure production web server is configured to handle files this large) or more, it has a Flash progress bar with nice styling and lots of options. Uploadify was covered on the [RailsTips blog](http://railstips.org/2009/7/21/uploadify-and-rails23) a while back.